# PHP: Receive one file sent by XHR Level 2

Tags: php, ajax, upload

The question is maybe somewhat noob, but I can't find this out. If I send a file using this way:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(file) {
    if ($scope.XHR2Support()) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
            console.log("PROGRESS", e.loaded, e.total);
        } 

        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log("Upload finished!");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Upload error", xhr.status);
            }
        }

        xhr.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Error occured", e);
        }

        xhr.open("POST", "./?files,upload&test=test", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
        xhr.send(file);
    }
  }
```

, how do I receive and save it with the right MIME-type with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save MIME type into the saved file. The browser decides which MIME type it is according to the file extension, unless `Content-type` HTTP header is sent.

You can read http headers sent by `xhr.setRequestHeader` using [apache_request_headers()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) on the server side.

To send the file by XHR2, the easiest way is to use `FormData` object, see the *Uploading file or blob* section [in this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/).